# Use TemplateField as PK for GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I would like to use an auto incremented template field instead of a DataKeyName as the factor in updating/deleting a GridView. My reasoning is because there can be multiple entries with the same ID (no pk in database).

Gridview Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter = "True"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
```

My code to auto increment column:

```
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" Visible="False" HeaderText="PK">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex +1 %>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using windowing (within a view) to mimic a primary key, and binding the view to the GridView rather than the table.

```
create table dbo.temp (TheData varchar(255));

go

insert into dbo.temp values ('Alpha'), ('Bravo'),  ('Charlie'), ('Delta'), ('Echo'), ('Foxtrox');

go

create view dbo.tempView 

as

select
    Id = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TheData), -- mimics primary key
    TheData
from
    dbo.temp

go

select Id, TheData from dbo.tempView; -- use this as your data source
```